# I have upgraded to Eclipse Indigo from Eclipse Galileo. My projects in my workspace now have errors

Tags: android, eclipse

I have upgraded to Eclipse Indigo from Eclipse Galileo. My projects in my workspace now have errors. I have errors even for import statements like this one:

```
import android.app.Activity;
```

However, I can use that same import statement in a new project with no problems. I have a feeling that the older projects are trying to use an older sdk that is no longer avaliable, however I am not sure of this. Is there some way or something in the project setup that is making it look for an older SDK or ADT?

Comment: It's way past time for bed, this has been giving me a very hard time since trying to upgrade, will check in a few hours when I wake.

Comment: Compare the build path of your project and with the one of a new project. The library containing `android.app.Activity` may be missing.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Ghost. I just tried it. Still have the errors.

Comment: Cool, I will check the build path.

Comment: Try fixing the build path. That may help, as our friend Baldrick suggests.

Comment: Ok, I'm not entirely sure what a build path is, but I figured out how to check it and it is indeed different. My older project is missing Android 4.0.3, so I guess I need to figure out how to add that to the build path.

Comment: Any idea how I add Android 4.0.3 to my old projects build path?

Comment: Alright, back at it again. So like I said my older projects have errors since upgrading to Indico. I have determined that the problem is indeed the build path. Does anyone know exactly how I can correct my build path? I have not been able to figure out how to add Android 4.0.3 to my build path, and I'm not sure if I did it, it would fix the problem.

Comment: Ok, I'm new to this stuff, but I'm learning, as of now I'm downloading the older SDK to use with my phone, This will be one step closer to fixing some problems.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Now I have the older version of the SDK installed. API 10, which is what all my older projects were created for. However my projects still contain all the errors, and I suspect it has something to do with the build path, or some other unknown nuiance. Any tips, I am pretty much over my head here, but I hope to get back on track soon.

Comment: Ok, after getting the new API 10 SDK installed, and using the fix project properties, many of the errors have resolved themselves. However the ones that remain all seem to have something to do with resources? the errors happen at lines of code like this:             setContentView(R.layout.main) and the errors say: R cannont be resolved to a variable. Any suggestions for a direction to explore in order to fix my errors?

Comment: Ok, I have my projects working again. This has been a learning experince, as I have never used softwares that have interdepencies like the IDE and SDK, I'm not sure what went wrong, but as of now The ecipse IDE is upgraded to Indigo, I have all The SDK's installed, and all my previous projects build again. Thankyou for all the help guys! Also I deleted some of my older questions that I thought were not very good(clean up the forum a bit) Well, I deleted 5 of them, and caused myself to be banned from asking questions. The faq says in need some upvotes to get back in good terms again! Upvote!